# SSL Handshake timeout when Corda Bridge of Transacting Party try to connect with Notary node

Tags: corda

A multi party private network with notary has been deployed. All the transacting parties are behind single shared Corda Firewall. Trying to verify the deployment using sample CorDapp (i.e. "corda-finance").

1. Transacting party A initiates Payment flow with Transacting Party B. The flow execution does not complete.

   > flow start CashPaymentFlow amount: $5, recipient: "O=Transacting Party
   >   B, L=Delhi, C=IN", anonymous: true, notary: "O=Notary HQ, L=London,
   >   C=GB"
2. The logs on Transacting Party A suggest that the flow is waiting to connect with Notary.

   > [INFO ] 2020-01-21T14:01:59,351Z [pool-13-thread-1]
   >   statemachine.FlowMonitor.logFlowsWaitingForParty - Flow with id
   >   9e0a1005-6e1f-400a-892e-e86c238e8d54 has been waiting for 2287 seconds
   >   to receive messages from parties [O=Notary HQ, L=London, C=GB]. {}
3. The logs on Bridge component suggest that there is SSL handshake time-out.

   > [WARN ] 2020-01-21T12:03:03,521Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2]
   >   netty.AMQPChannelHandler. - SSL Handshake timed out
   >   {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=Notary HQ, L=London, C=GB, localCert=null,
   >   remoteAddress=elb-notaryhq.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/XX.XXX.XXX.XX:10002,
   >   remoteCert=null, serverMode=false}
   >       [ERROR] 2020-01-21T12:03:03,521Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPChannelHandler. - Handshake failure: handshake timed out
   >   {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=Notary HQ, L=London, C=GB, localCert=null,
   >   remoteAddress=elb-notaryhq.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/XX.XXX.XXX.XX:10002,
   >   remoteCert=null, serverMode=false}
4. The SSL certificate chain for Transacting Party A & Notary node has been verified. It has common trusted root certificate.The Transcting Party A node can communicate with Notary HQ node on any port. There is no restriction currently.
5. From the source code on github, it seems SSLException has been thrown.

   > https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.4/node-api/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/nodeapi/internal/protonwrapper/netty/AMQPChannelHandler.kt

What could be the possbile cause for this issue?

Comment: Are you using CENM?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is an issue with not having the keys at the correct place.

I would suggest you to take look at the tutorial at [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.5/ha-utilities.html). The HA Utilities aims to provide tools to streamline the node provision and deployment process.